# Why am I getting expression must have class type error?

Tags: c++

I was trying to run this simple block of code and I got the error: expression must have class type for `tom.name` and `tom.id`. What have I done wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    string name;
    int id;
    int age;
};


int main()
{
    Student* tom = new Student;
    tom.name = "tom";
    tom.id = 1;
}
```

Comment: you didn't include the header for string

Comment: Either `Student tom;` or `tom->name`, `tom->id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the pointer incorrectly. Accessing inner variables from a pointer require `->` instead of the `.` operator.

Switch your code:

```cpp
Student* student_ptr = new Student;
student_ptr->name = "Tom";
student_ptr->id = 1;
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want to use the `.` operator, you can do:

```cpp
Student* student_ptr = new Student;
(*student_ptr).name = "Tom";
(*student_ptr).id = 1; // the more you know
```